# Showing UILabel on iPhone video application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5

I need to show some text on the running video in my iPhone application. I am using `AVFOUNDATION.FRAMEWORK` to stream my videos. What exactly I need is that, for example, if my video length is about 5 minutes then I want to show text on the video from minute 3 to minute 4 then at the end of the video for few seconds.

I have placed a UIView with UILabel on the video view, which is properly showing the text on it but it is constantly there. I want to limit this text so that whenever I want to show it on my video it comes up.

Is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean in fulscreen mode?? Or when your controls appear??

Comment: Through AVPlayer I have drawn my own view not a full screen. Whenever the video starts I want to show text on it from time to time. Like you would have seen in some videos that while you watch the video a tag of the company shows for some seconds and then goes and then comes back at some other time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should set a NSTimer with delay and fire it when you want to show the label and again use another timer to hide it and so on. ie, set timer according, you will have to manually set it.